# Is there a global "current" for each core if Linux is running on a multicore CPU?

Tags: linux, multicore

Some book says

> The **current** pointer refers to the user process currently executing.
>   During the execution of a system call, such as **open** or **read**, the
>   current process is the one that invoked the call.

What if multiple processes are calling a system call (same or different system calls) at the same time on a multicore CPU, one on each core? Does the kernel need multiple "current" global variables for them?

Answer (score 4):

If you're curious as to how this is implemented: on x86-64, each CPU's `gs` selector register is used to point to a block of data specific to that CPU.  This makes it easy to access that data with a single instruction.

As hobbs points out, `current` is a macro which expands to a call to an inline function, which via a few other inline functions and inline asm, expands to an instruction like

```
movq %gs:current_task,%rax
```

which loads this CPU's `current` pointer into the `rax` register.  Here the label `current_task` is the offset of the `current` pointer within the per-CPU data block, and is computed and filled in by the linker (or module loader).

You can see details in `include/asm/percpu.h`.

Answer (score 2):

`current` is in fact a macro, not a variable. But yes, it's a macro that reads a per-CPU variable, meaning it will always return the current task for the CPU it's executing from. [Here is its definition](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h#L17) for x86, and [here is where it's set](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L405) in `__switch_to` for 64-bit x86.

Comment: In olden days, before multiple processors were supported, it actually was a global variable ([example from Linux 0.01](https://github.com/zavg/linux-0.01/blob/master/kernel/sched.c)), and the macro is designed so that you still write your code as though it were a global variable.

Comment: @NateEldredge makes sense. I've been around a while, but my knowledge still doesn't go back beyond Linux 2.0 :)